# New page in account dashboard

Tags: custom, customer-account, tabs

This is my current customer_account.xml file I am able to get the tab to display inside of the account dashboard but I am not able to render the page I need.

My current file path is html/app/design/frontend/Babble/lighting/Magecomp_Savecartpro/layout/

Im lost on what would be the next step after this. I have followed some tutorials but they all are outdated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-myquote" after="-" ifconfig="savecartpro/general/enable">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">savecartpro/customer/cartlist</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Saved Projects</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-your-second-link" after="-" ifconfig="savecartpro/general/enable">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">helloworld/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Your Second Link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is my full folder

This is driving me crazy
[image]

Comment: Have you checked answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your above code is proper. Now you need to create controller file(according to the path you mentioned in xml file), after that need to create layout and phtml file same as below.

**I assume that you have created routes.xml file already.**

> According to your code please create controller file cartlist.php
> under path PackageName/Module/Controller/Customer/

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\Module\Controller\Customer;

class Cartlist extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    
    /**
     * Prepare collection page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();  
        return $this->resultPage;
    }
}
```

> Now please create layout file savecartpro_customer_cartlist.xml under
> path PackageName/Module/view/frontend/layout/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <head>
        <title>Cart List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">         
            <block class="PackageName\Module\Block\Customer\Cartlist" name="custom_list" template="custom/collection.phtml" cacheable="false"></block>
        </referenceContainer> 
    </body>
</page>
```

> Please create collection.phtml file under path
> PackageName/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom/

```
<div class="">Test</div>
```

> Please create block file Cartlist.php under path
> PackageName/Module/Block/Customer/

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\Module\Block\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Cartlist extends Template
{
    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    */

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

Please create functions in block and show data in phtml file according to your need.

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry I have not created a routes xml the tutorial I followed never mentioned one

Comment: am I supposed to add these files to the vender folder?

Comment: Why in vendor folder? You should create custom module for that